# Linq: Select items and change values in a single line?

Tags: vb.net, linq

Let's say I have a this code:

```
Private Class User
   Public Property Name As String
   Public Property Age As Integer
   Public Property Salary As Decimal
   Public Property Handled As Boolean
End Class

Private _users As New List(Of User)
```

I know I can select users like this...

```
Dim data = _users.Where(Function(f) f.Age > 30)
```

But can I change values in the same line? I was hoping for something like this...

```
_users.Where(Function(f) f.Age > 30).Salary = 3000
```

Or if changing two values...

```
_users.Where(Function(f) f.Age > 30).Each(Function(m) m.Salary = 3000, m.Handled = True)
```

But any of the above doesn't work ... is it possible to do something similar on one line of code?

Thanks

Comment: `users.Where(Function(f) f.Age > 30 AndAlso f.Age < 40).ToList().ForEach(Sub(s)
                                                                                    s.Salary += 10
                                                                                    s.Handled = True
                                                                                End Sub)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, you cannot both select and modify the original collection. (I can be wrong-- haven't tried it lately.)

What can work is to do a `Select` and create new instances from the existing data.

Note: this sample uses string interpolation, which is a feature of the compiler that ships with VS 2015.  I also ignored the `Handled` property.

E.g., filter and modify all returned users to have age of 100:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/uudyTG

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1
    Dim users as New List(Of User)()

    Public Sub Main()
        users.AddRange({
            new User() With {.Name = "a", .Age = 1, .Salary = 100D},
            new User() With {.Name = "b", .Age = 11, .Salary = 100D},
            new User() With {.Name = "c", .Age = 13, .Salary = 100D},
            new User() With {.Name = "d", .Age = 15, .Salary = 100D},
            new User() With {.Name = "e", .Age = 21, .Salary = 100D},
            new User() With {.Name = "f", .Age = 24, .Salary = 100D}
        })


        Dim filteredUsers As IEnumerable(Of User) = users.Where(function(u) u.Age > 15).Select(Function(u) new User() With {.Name = u.Name, .Age = 100, .Salary = u.Salary})

                    Console.WriteLine("Filtered Users:")
                For Each u in filteredUsers
                    Console.WriteLine(u)
                next u

                Console.WriteLine("Original Users, still unmodified:")
                For Each u in users
                    Console.WriteLine(u)
                next u
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class User
   Public Property Name As String
   Public Property Age As Integer
   Public Property Salary As Decimal
   Public Property Handled As Boolean

                    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
                        Return $"Name: {Name}, Age: {Age}, Salary: {Salary}"
                    End Function
End Class
```

**OUTPUT** -- Note how the original collection is not modified.

```
Filtered Users:
Name: e, Age: 100, Salary: 100
Name: f, Age: 100, Salary: 100
Original Users, still unmodified:
Name: a, Age: 1, Salary: 100
Name: b, Age: 11, Salary: 100
Name: c, Age: 13, Salary: 100
Name: d, Age: 15, Salary: 100
Name: e, Age: 21, Salary: 100
Name: f, Age: 24, Salary: 100
```